# Is there a way to pull changes in bitbucket from the Web UI?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

Or do I have to pull to my home repo and then push to my fork on bitbucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you have to make a pull request first in Bitbucket. You can then approve the pull request and the changesets will be pulled on Bitbucket itself without you having to down and upload them.